# How to show staggred gridImageView inside cardview in Recyclerview Case

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to implement image recyclerView (Staggered layout manager) inside cardView which teh cardView is item on recyclerView. I have a question when I build. Shall I call recyclerView adapter class inside class ViewHolder? or making custom adapter class so that I can call at one activity class? or Any suggestion?

This design describes  my output expectation
[image: Design Layout wanna be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Recycler view like always and with his adapter, in the layout of the item for the recycler just add an ImageView to set with the picture
2. In the layout of the MainActivity you can use of layout parent the CardView with orientation vertical, and inside you will add the recyclerView and the TextView, both with height 0dp, and you'll add a weight of 0.8 for the Recycler View and weight of 0.2 for the TextView
3. When you set in the java the adapter of RecyclerView, you need to say in Grid(2) for be just 2 column

and it's done, I hope this can help something

Comment: How about adapter class recycler view inside cardView? should I declare just one class adapter Recycler View?

Comment: Yes, Always hen you going to use a RecyclerView you will need three extra things, 

1) Create you, object Class, if you going to show the list about something in Special like Class Person
2)Create your AdapterClass with the inner class ViewHolder
3)Create your extra layout for each item

Comment: I see. Thank you